# Map <option> of a materialize css <select> with ReactJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, materialize

I'm working in a React component that must implement a `<select><option>`
functionality.

I have this:

```
<div className="input-field col s12">
      <select>      
        <option value="" disabled>Choose your option</option>

         {projects.map(function(projects, index) {                    
                  return (
      <option value={projects.name} key={projects.name}>
         {projects.name}
      </option>
            )})}           
     </select>
     <label>Project</label>
     </div>
```

I also have the materialize select initialized in `componentDidMount()`:

```
componentDidMount: function() {

    //initialize selects
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('select').material_select();
    });
}, 
 (...)
```

But when the component is displayed, it appears without `<options>`. When debugging the generated html in the web source code with inspection tool it has the options with display none, but when changing to block, it creates a new select after it, with no style.

Any ideas? Thanks so much.

Comment: Is this your actual code? You can't just say `return` in the middle of jsx like that.. looks like you're missing `map`?

Comment: I pasted wrong, the code sorry!!

Comment: I'm seeing that is a problem of the state recovering the data, rather than the materializecss (what I thought at first because of the strange behaviour).

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the problem!!!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('select').material_select();
        });
```

MUST be executed, when the select is displayed, not only when the component is mounted. So I didn't need to execute the initialization function of the select in the componentDidMount() phase function, but in render() function, because every time the state changed (and it changes because it's populated with json data), I must execute the jquery function above.

Solved! Hope it helps any other one.